# Script tag injection fails in my docs.python.org search userscript

Tags: javascript, userscripts

Python's documentation website has a search feature. The results are a list of links to various places in the python documentation. All of these result links have the form

https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html?highlight=__future__#module-__future__

The highlight query parameter causes "**future**" to get highlighted at the destination. I don't want this behaviour. So, I'm writing a userscript that changes the search results page, removing the `?highlight=__future__` etc from every link.

This would have been easy, except that the results are generated dynamically. So, I couldn't just find all `<a>` tags underneath `<li>` tags and edit the `href`s. If I tried that, no tags would be found, since they don't exist until a few seconds after the page loads. If I delayed the replacement script for a few seconds after the page loads, the fix wouldn't work until this delay expired. And in the case of a long search, the results can take many seconds to all come in. The only good way to apply the fix is to edit the javascript making the result tags. This is what I tried. Here's the script so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         python-search-no-highlight
// @version      0.3
// @description  Disables highlighting in docs.python.org's search results.
// @match        http://docs.python.org/*
// @match        https://docs.python.org/*
// @match        http://*.docs.python.org/*
// @match        https://*.docs.python.org/*
// @namespace    https://greasyfork.org/users/217495-eric-toombs
// ==/UserScript==


script_text = `
Search.query = function(query) {
    var i;

    // stem the searchterms and add them to the correct list
    var stemmer = new Stemmer();
    var searchterms = [];
    var excluded = [];
    var hlterms = [];
    var tmp = splitQuery(query);
    var objectterms = [];
    for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
      if (tmp[i] !== "") {
          objectterms.push(tmp[i].toLowerCase());
      }

      if ($u.indexOf(stopwords, tmp[i].toLowerCase()) != -1 || tmp[i].match(/^\d+$/) ||
          tmp[i] === "") {
        // skip this "word"
        continue;
      }
      // stem the word
      var word = stemmer.stemWord(tmp[i].toLowerCase());
      // prevent stemmer from cutting word smaller than two chars
      if(word.length < 3 && tmp[i].length >= 3) {
        word = tmp[i];
      }
      var toAppend;
      // select the correct list
      if (word[0] == '-') {
        toAppend = excluded;
        word = word.substr(1);
      }
      else {
        toAppend = searchterms;
        hlterms.push(tmp[i].toLowerCase());
      }
      // only add if not already in the list
      if (!$u.contains(toAppend, word))
        toAppend.push(word);
    }

// THIS IS THE LINE I MODIFIED!
    var highlightstring = '';

    // console.debug('SEARCH: searching for:');
    // console.info('required: ', searchterms);
    // console.info('excluded: ', excluded);

    // prepare search
    var terms = Search._index.terms;
    var titleterms = Search._index.titleterms;

    // array of [filename, title, anchor, descr, score]
    var results = [];
    $('#search-progress').empty();

    // lookup as object
    for (i = 0; i < objectterms.length; i++) {
      var others = [].concat(objectterms.slice(0, i),
                             objectterms.slice(i+1, objectterms.length));
      results = results.concat(Search.performObjectSearch(objectterms[i], others));
    }

    // lookup as search terms in fulltext
    results = results.concat(Search.performTermsSearch(searchterms, excluded, terms, titleterms));

    // let the scorer override scores with a custom scoring function
    if (Scorer.score) {
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        results[i][4] = Scorer.score(results[i]);
    }

    // now sort the results by score (in opposite order of appearance, since the
    // display function below uses pop() to retrieve items) and then
    // alphabetically
    results.sort(function(a, b) {
      var left = a[4];
      var right = b[4];
      if (left > right) {
        return 1;
      } else if (left < right) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        // same score: sort alphabetically
        left = a[1].toLowerCase();
        right = b[1].toLowerCase();
        return (left > right) ? -1 : ((left < right) ? 1 : 0);
      }
    });

    // for debugging
    //Search.lastresults = results.slice();  // a copy
    //console.info('search results:', Search.lastresults);

    // print the results
    var resultCount = results.length;
    function displayNextItem() {
      // results left, load the summary and display it
      if (results.length) {
        var item = results.pop();
        var listItem = $('<li style="display:none"></li>');
        var requestUrl = "";
        if (DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS.BUILDER === 'dirhtml') {
          // dirhtml builder
          var dirname = item[0] + '/';
          if (dirname.match(/\/index\/$/)) {
            dirname = dirname.substring(0, dirname.length-6);
          } else if (dirname == 'index/') {
            dirname = '';
          }
          requestUrl = DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS.URL_ROOT + dirname;

        } else {
          // normal html builders
          requestUrl = DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS.URL_ROOT + item[0] + DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS.FILE_SUFFIX;
        }
        listItem.append($('<a/>').attr('href',
            requestUrl +
            highlightstring + item[2]).html(item[1]));
        if (item[3]) {
          listItem.append($('<span> (' + item[3] + ')</span>'));
          Search.output.append(listItem);
          listItem.slideDown(5, function() {
            displayNextItem();
          });
        } else if (DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS.HAS_SOURCE) {
          $.ajax({url: requestUrl,
                  dataType: "text",
                  complete: function(jqxhr, textstatus) {
                    var data = jqxhr.responseText;
                    if (data !== '' && data !== undefined) {
                      listItem.append(Search.makeSearchSummary(data, searchterms, hlterms));
                    }
                    Search.output.append(listItem);
                    listItem.slideDown(5, function() {
                      displayNextItem();
                    });
                  }});
        } else {
          // no source available, just display title
          Search.output.append(listItem);
          listItem.slideDown(5, function() {
            displayNextItem();
          });
        }
      }
      // search finished, update title and status message
      else {
        Search.stopPulse();
        Search.title.text(_('Search Results'));
        if (!resultCount)
          Search.status.text(_('Your search did not match any documents. Please make sure that all words are spelled correctly and that you\'ve selected enough categories.'));
        else
            Search.status.text(_('Search finished, found %s page(s) matching the search query.').replace('%s', resultCount));
        Search.status.fadeIn(500);
      }
    }
    displayNextItem();
  };
`;


script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.text = script_text;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

This script fails with the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list search.html:106:60
```

When I go to click on `search.html:106:60`, it leads me to the static page, so of course my changes aren't there.

When I copy the javascript I'm trying to inject and paste it into the console directly, it works fine. So, I know there isn't even a syntax error. When I replace the function I want to insert with a much simpler test one, like

```
Search.query = function() {
    // This is a comment.
    console.log('</test>');
};
```

it works fine. What the hell's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out. I thought that javascript backtick literals did not treat backslashes specially, but it turns out, they do. I just had to escape all backslashes in the backtick literal, and it worked! So, let that be a lesson: whenever storing javascript in a backtick literal, always escape the backslashes. Oh, and the dollar signs and the backticks.